# Wildfly 8 with inifinispan Java thread

Tags: multithreading, wildfly-8, infinispan

I am using [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org) in a WildFly 8 server.

In my application I am using normal java threads and timers. So how can I use it in Infinispan distributed mode with 4 nodes and 2 owners?

**My Problem:**
The thread wakes up every 15 mins in all nodes and inserting 4 times same data in DB. But I want single thread for all nodes.

Comment: Maybe you need a [Wildfly singleton](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/cluster-ha-singleton) to be deployed in the cluster to do that work?

Comment: Ok, thank you.i tried singleton but i got this ERROR:  Clustered annotation is deprecated and will be ignored."

Comment: Are you sure it's an error? If an annotation is deprecated and hence it's ignored, that's likely a warning message. See https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/8.x/cluster-ha-singleton for example.

Comment: Sorry WARN only . this warning because of Coding or Wildfly setup problem ?

Comment: I guess because of your code, I guess you should remove @Clustered, but anyway, just follow the quickstart and you should good to go :)